# Get function parameters name visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to get a list of parameters and the return type from a mangled function compiled in visual studio.

I know that I can use

```
UnDecorateSymbolName(function.c_str(), undecoratedName, 200, UNDNAME_COMPLETE))
```

but this just gives me another string, and I have to figure out if the string starts with a return type, or a specifier.

Is there a function to return SymbolNameInfo? Something along the lines:

```
struct SymbolInfo
{
    char[255] symbolName
    char[255] returnType
    char[255] parameters
};
```

Comment: What's a "mangled" function? :)

Comment: @ChrisLava you can read about it [here](http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/)

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Here I thought it surely it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer. It's not perfect, maybe someone else will have some better idea.

What I did was use

```
UnDecorateSymbolName(function.c_str(), undecoratedName, 200, UNDNAME_COMPLETE))
```

with different flags.

The flags I used with explanation:

```
UNDNAME_COMPLETE // this returns the whole undecorated name.
UNDNAME_NAME_ONLY // this return just the name of the symbol
UNDNAME_NO_FUNCTION_RETURNS // this return a string like UNDNAME_COMPLETE 
                            // but without the return type
```

I used these 3 flags to do the following:

1. To get the name, I just used UNDNAME_NAME_ONLY.
2. To get the return type, I did a substring of COMPLETE ending at NO_FUNCTION_RETURNS
3. To get the parameters, I did a substring of COMPLETE starting at the end of NAME ending at COMPLETE.size()

How this looks after test:

```
function : ?encrypt@@YAPADPAD@Z 
fullName : char * __cdecl encrypt(char*)

SymbolInfo.name : encrypt 
SymbolInfo.returnType : char *
SymbolInfo.parameters : (char *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get unmangled name is probably to use Microsoft's `undname.exe`, installed with Visual Studio.

For doing it programmatically, look at e.g. (http://code.google.com/p/pdbparse/source/browse/trunk/src/undname.c)<sup>*</sup>.

The above two references the result of a minute or so of googling. ;-)

---

<sub>*: jus’ hoping that some helpful bear won't come along to swat that perceived fly on my nose, but they always do</sub>

Comment: The question is, how to turn the resulting string into semantic information. Both of your suggested tools do just what the OP already has.

Comment: @IInspectable no, the question was if there was any other way to get the semantic information other then the one I provided.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it seems that this is the source of the library that I am already using. I don't think there are any function available that return what I want.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: oh, it appeared that you used Microsoft's `UnDecorateSymbolName`. the `undname.c` source implements just about the same, but includes all the internals which you can use as you see fit. i don't know which came first, but i guess that `undname.c` is reverse-engineering (useful for doing this on one's own, with any desired features).

Comment: @Bartlomiej `undname.exe` calls `UnDecorateSymbolName`. The google-code link posted is an approximate reverse-engineered implementation of `UnDecorateSymbolName`. Neither one adds anything to your using `UnDecorateSymbolName`, hence the downvote ("This answer is not useful").